# Form not showing properly with Plesk on Mac Mail

Tags: php, forms, email, phpmailer, plesk

I have a form that is emailing and posting to the database as it should. The problem is that when it sends to email addresses on our own server (Parallels Plesk) and it comes into Mac Mail it comes through a little corrupt. The text is broken up and there's $= all over the form. Sometimes it even has part of the html coding sat at the top of the email, like:

```
<= /tr><= td colspan='3'>Further Comments: 

= <= /tr><= td width='40%' colspan='2'>Expectations
```

But everytime it's slightly different. I.e. there's no thing it does everytime it comes through; everytime the symbols and coding is a little different.

This is my code for emailing it:

```
<?php
$servername = "***";
$username = "***";
$password = "***";
$dbname = "***";


try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO guestquestionnaire (date_submitted, choice, expectations, res, res_information, res_staff, further_comments1)
    VALUES (:date_submitted, :choice, :expectations, :res, :res_information, :res_staff, :further_comments1)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':date_submitted', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':choice', $choice);
    $stmt->bindParam(':expectations', $expectations);
    $stmt->bindParam(':res', $res);
    $stmt->bindParam(':res_information', $res_information);
    $stmt->bindParam(':res_staff', $res_staff);
    $stmt->bindParam(':further_comments1', $further_comments1);


    // insert a row
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $choice = $_POST['choice'];
    $expectations = $_POST['expectations'];
    $res = $_POST['res'];
    $res_information = $_POST['res_information'];
    $res_staff = $_POST['res_staff'];
    $further_comments1 = $_POST['further_comments1'];
    $stmt->execute();

    }

catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
$conn = null;



?>



<?php

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//PHPMailer Object
$mail = new PHPMailer;

//From email address and name
$mail->From = "info@personalemail.com";
$mail->FromName = "Host Person";

//To address and name
$mail->addAddress("user@icloud.com", "User");
$mail->addAddress("info@personalemail.com"); //Recipient name is optional

//Address to which recipient will reply
$mail->addReplyTo("info@personalemail.com", "Reply");

//CC and BCC
$mail->addCC("cc@example.com");
$mail->addBCC("bcc@example.com");

//Send HTML or Plain Text email
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Guest Questionnaire Received";


// Build message.

$img="<img src='http://www.myurl.com/guestquestionnaire/images/star".$_POST['res'].".jpg'>";

$img2="<img src='http://www.myurl.com/guestquestionnaire/images/star".$_POST['res_information'].".jpg'>";

$img3="<img src='http://www.myurl.com/guestquestionnaire/images/star".$_POST['res_staff'].".jpg'>";

            $message = '<html><body>';  
            $message .=  "<strong>Guest Questionnaire </strong>";
            $message .=  "<strong>Received: </strong>";
            $message .=  "<P>";

            $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border: 1px solid #999;" cellpadding="7" width="100%" >';

            $message .= "<tr style='background: #566890; font-size: 8pt; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;'><td colspan='3'>Prior to Arrival</td></tr>";


            $message .= "<tr style='font-size: 8pt;'><td>What made you choose us for your recent trip? </td><td width='40%' colspan='2'>" . strip_tags($_POST['choice']) . "</td></tr>";

            $message .= "<tr style='font-size: 8pt;'><td>Did we meet your expectations as advertised? If no, please state why: </td><td width='40%' colspan='2'>" . strip_tags($_POST['expectations']) . "</td></tr>";

                        $message .= "<tr style='background: #566890; font-size: 8pt; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;'><td colspan='3'>Making your Reservation</td></tr>";


            $message .= "<tr style='font-size: 8pt;'><td>Ease of making your reservation: </td><td width='40%'>$img</td><td width='5%'>" . strip_tags($_POST['res']) . "</td></tr>";


            $message .= "<tr style='font-size: 8pt;'><td>Hotel information offered: </td><td width='40%'>$img2</td><td width='5%'>" . strip_tags($_POST['res_information']) . "</td></tr>";


            $message .= "<tr style='font-size: 8pt;'><td>Warmth and friendliness of staff: </td><td width='40%'>$img3</td><td width='5%'>" . strip_tags($_POST['res_staff']) . "</td></tr>";

            $message .= "<tr style='font-size: 8pt;'><td colspan='3'>Further Comments: </BR></BR>" . strip_tags($_POST['further_comments1']) . "</td></tr>";


            $message .= "</table>";

            $message .=  "<BR>";





            $message .= "</table>";
            $message .= "</body></html>";
$message .= "</body></html>";

$mail->Body = "".$message."";


if(!$mail->send()) 
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="surveystyle.css" media="all" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.inputfocus-0.9.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.main.js"></script>



     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">


                <div class="logo-header"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="" width="205" height="119" /></div>
```

I have really gone through so many different ways to identify that the problem is somewhere between this particular form, our server and Mac Mail. I believe something can be changed on this form to make it work (I just don't know what). The form displays fine on the webmail platform and other email accounts (not on our server) display the form perfectly fine.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!!!

UPDATE:

I went through and removed each line to see if I could try and investigate error. It seems that the problem is to do with the length of the form. If there are 10 entries or so it goes through fine (regardless of what the field is) but once it's over 10 entries it starts giving all the weird $= all over the place. Very weird. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to check the content at each stage - solve one problem at a time. You can check what the assembled message looks like before it is sent by calling `$mail->presend();` then `$mail->getSentMIMEMessage();` before you call `send()`. Also if you submit the message to your mail server (even if it's on localhost) via SMTP, you may find it's faster and you will get more control over debugging.

Comment: Hi @Synchro I actually just did that funnily enough (checking the content at each stage). Please see my updated message. Might you know what's causing that? It's something to do with the height :)

Comment: Why are you writing `</BR>` instead of `<BR>`?

Comment: I can't even see where I am writing </BR> ?

Comment: Oh I just saw it in 'Further Comments'. I don't think that's the problem though. Even if I remove them all it still does the same thing.

Comment: Even with your update, it's not clear that you're checking the content at each stage. At one point your content will be ok, and at the next it will not; you need to find out when that is. Only looking at the end product is not going to help.

Comment: Yes, I did that. I removed every single line and added them in 1 by 1. Regardless of what content is on that line - i.e. I could have the same field over and over for 9 fields, as soon as I add the 10th field is corrupts. I tried every different option and the content of the actual file has nothing to do with the errors; it's the height. As soon as it exceeds 10 fields or so it goes all funny. So yes, my content it okay at 9 fields but not at 10 fields. What coding is there makes ZERO difference (I spent about 2 hours on these tests).